# Why datagridview not display data only when I focused the row the data is appearing?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

Sorry for this amateurish question but after a few hours of searching I have to ask you what is the problem? 
I use Entity framework and return list to the data source.
The records return but the datagridview does not display them only when I click on row the data is appearing.

This is what I try:

```
var context = new PetHotelDBEntities();                       
dgvCustomerSuppliers.DataSource=context.Customers.ToList<Customers>();
dgvCustomerSuppliers.Refresh();
```

Also using Binding List:

```
List<Customers> customers = context.Customers.ToList<Customers>(); 
BindingList<Customers> view = new BindingList<Customers>(customers);
dgvCustomerSuppliers.DataSource = view;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the foreground color set to white by any chance?

Comment: Genius! I forgot about that.